# shifting everything down in an array as a form of deletion java iterable

Tags: java, arrays, iterator, iterable

so I'm trying to remove an element from an array by shifting everything down after I remove it and this is what I have so far

```
for (int i = 0; i < numShapes; i++){ 
     shapes[i] = shapes[i-1]; 
     numShapes--;
}
```

so if my array contained 
`Joe Jen Jess`

and I called my .next() and .remove() method it'd look like

`Joe Jess null`

my .next() method returns the next item in my iterator and my remove method is meant to remove the item

```
remove method
 public void remove() throws IllegalStateException { 
     if (cursor <= numShapes-1 || cursor == 0){ 
        throw new IllegalStateException();
     }
     if (numShapes == 0){ throw new NoSuchElementException(); } 

     for (int i = 0; i < numShapes; i++){ 
     shapes[i] = shapes[i-1]; 
     numShapes--;
}
```

is the implementation of remove correct? does it properly shift the elements once removed?

Comment: What is your specific question? I see none in your post above.

Comment: What problem are you having?

Comment: my remove() method doesn't shift properly

Comment: shapes[i] = shapes[i-1]; 
This line won't work for the first round when i=0. shapes[0]= shapes[-1] is not correct. It will give exception

Comment: You are shifting elements the wrong direction and start with an invalid index.  Time to step through the code one line at a time in your debugger.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the index of the element you want to delete and then shift the other elements using that index and set the last value as `null` as below sample code:

```
int index = -1;
String searchStr = "FindMe";

for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (searchStr.equals(array[i])) {
        index = i;
        break;
    }
}

if (index > -1) {
    for (int i = index; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i+1];
    }
}

array[array.length - 1] = null;
```